# DeSerialize DataTable Row Collection into List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

I have a DataTable with rows of data.  I have a class with properties that match the row column names.

How can I have a List that is populated from the DataTable Row information?

Do I call something like (MyType)new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType)).Deserialize(new XMLReader(Table.WriteXML()));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend writing classes to perform this transformation instead of using XML serialization, which requires a lot of extra work and ties your objects too closely to your data model.

On the other hand, sometimes you just have to deserialize collections from XML. To accomplish this, *all you need to do is tell the* `XmlSerializer` *which node to map to the collection*.

By default, `DataTable.WriteXml` creates a root element called `<DocumentElement>`. For example, if you write from a `DataTable` called "Name" that has "FirstName" and "LastName" columns, you'll get this:

```
<DocumentElement>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>Jon</FirstName>
        <LastName>User</LastName>
    </Name>
</DocumentElement>
```

The problem is that the `XmlSerializer` doesn't know that "DocumentElement" should be deserialized to your collection class. There are two ways to tell it how.

#### By Convention

The `XmlSerializer` knows that a root element named "ArrayOfMyClass" should map to collections of `MyClass`.

Add your `DataTable` to a `DataSet` named "ArrayOfMyClass" to serialize it like this ...

```
<ArrayOfMyClass>
    <MyClass>
    // ... elements that map to properties of MyClass
    </MyClass>
</ArrayOfMyClass>
```

.... which deserializes into a `List<MyClass>` as desired.

#### By Hand

As an alternative, you can do it like this:

```
XmlRootAttribute root       = new XmlRootAttribute("DocumentElement");
XmlSerializer    serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Name>), root);
```

Presuming everything else is ok (that is, your data row column names match your class' property names), this will deserialize as expected into your `List<MyClass>`.

Edit: note that this approach has a rather severe problem (with a moderately cumbersome workaround) described in this SO question: [XmlSerializer Performance Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534810/xmlserializer-performance-issue/1545340#1545340).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I used the example below in the end because as you say I am creating more work however you answered my question! Thanks

Comment: No problem - I just discovered an ugly problem with one of the approaches I suggested (though it has a workaround), which I've linked above. All the better that you chose the non-XML-oriented implementation. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to put the fields of each row of data into instances of YourClass and then store the instances in a List?

In that case, the most straightforward way is to

```
create the List object
loop over the rows
   create a new YourClass object
   map the fields to the properties of the YourClass object
   add the YourClass object to the list
```

Comment: I just thought there may be a quicker way with the XMLSerializer class but not sure there is

Comment: By 'quicker', do you mean, 'generic'?

Comment: I guess? Previously I have had XML and used the XMLSerilaizer but that is when I only had one instance of it. In this approach I now have X amount of rows and therefore want a List<MyType>.