# Memory leak in XmlSerializer as used in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks, xmlserializer

I seem to have a memory leak when using xmlSerializer in VB.net 2010.
The code below is the guts of a function which is called every 20 seconds or so forever.
Uncommenting the line 'serializer.Serialize(writer, response)' sees the memory usage climb.

```
 Using writer As New StreamWriter(fileName)
    Dim request = invoker.CreateRequest()
    Dim response = invoker.Invoke(authorization, request)
    If Not response Is Nothing Then 'maybe token timeout
        Dim serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(TResponse)) ', New XmlRootAttribute("TResponse"))
        Try
            '  serializer.Serialize(writer, response)

        Catch e As InvalidOperationException
            Dim msg As String = "ERROR: Failed to serialize the response:" & vbCrLf & e.Message
            AddToRtfEventLog(category.ToUpper & " DATA " & msg, Drawing.Color.Red)
        End Try
        serializer = Nothing
        AddToStatus(Convert.ToString("Response saved as ") & fileName & vbCrLf, Drawing.Color.LightGray, True)
    End If
    Return response
End Using
```

From internet reading, I gather this is a bug in the VB xmlSerializer and a possible solution is to use it in a caching manner. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do that so I wonder if someone can help me out here.
Firstly, am I doing it right in the first place (it works fine, just the memory issue) and
Secondly, if I am, can you show me how to fix the leak please?

Thanks
Malcom

Part 2-
With help from Jehof, I've now got the following cache class in place:
    Public NotInheritable Class XmlSerializerCache
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    Private Shared ReadOnly cache As New Dictionary(Of String, XmlSerializer)()

```
Public Shared Function Create(type As Type, root As XmlRootAttribute) As XmlSerializer
    Dim key = [String].Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}:{1}", type, root.ElementName)

    If Not cache.ContainsKey(key) Then
        cache.Add(key, New XmlSerializer(type, root))
    End If

    Return cache(key)
End Function
```

End Class

and have replaced the calls with :

```
 Dim xmlRootAttribute = New XmlRootAttribute("TResponse")
                    Dim serializer = XmlSerializerCache.Create(GetType(TResponse), XmlRootAttribute)
                    Try
                        serializer.Serialize(writer, response)
```

Thats has improved the leak but is the correct way to do this? To me it seems that I am recreating the cache with each call?

Comment: take a look at this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534810/xmlserializer-performance-issue-when-specifying-xmlrootattribute). I think it may help you

Comment: Thanks @jehof, I missed that one in my searches. It helps but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it. I've edited my original question to include this.