# c#, XML How to cycle through an XML node fetched with XMLNode.SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, xml

I have this class which represent a node TestCase in my XML :

```
public class TestCase
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string verdict { get; set; }
    public string objective { get; set; }
    public string criteria { get; set; }
    public string issue { get; set; }
    public string clientcomments { get; set; }
    public string authoritycomments { get; set; }
    public string sdk { get; set; }   

}
```

I use XmlNode.SelectSingleNode to fetch a specific node in my XML. For info, there are no duplicate nodes (no nodes with the same name attribute) if it matters.

So far, I have this code :

```
public static TestCase FetchNode(string NodeName, string Path)
    {
        TestCase testcase = new TestCase();
        string[] attr = { "name", "version", "verdict", "objective", "criteria"
                , "issue", "clientcomments", "authoritycomments", "sdk" };
        string[] attrval = { null, null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null};

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Path);

        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/TestsList/TestCase[@name='" + NodeName + "']");

        for (var i = 0; i == attr.Length - 1;i++)
        {
            attrval[i] = node[attr[i]].InnerText;
        }

        testcase.name = attrval[0];
        testcase.version = attrval[1];
        testcase.verdict = attrval[2];
        testcase.objective = attrval[3];
        testcase.criteria = attrval[4];
        testcase.issue = attrval[5];
        testcase.clientcomments = attrval[6];
        testcase.authoritycomments = attrval[7];
        testcase.sdk = attrval[8];

        return testcase;

    }
```

However, this code is not scalable at all, if I change my class structure, I would need to change the function because each element of the class are hardcoded in it.

This is a wide request, but how could I write this function so if I add or remove a string in the class definition of TestCase, I don`t have to change the function FetchNode.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [XmlSerializer.Deserialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class TestCase
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string verdict { get; set; }
    public string objective { get; set; }
    public string criteria { get; set; }
    public string issue { get; set; }
    public string clientcomments { get; set; }
    public string authoritycomments { get; set; }
    public string sdk { get; set; }   
}

public class Program
{
    public const string XML = @"
<TestCase name='TicketName'>
    <name>Jon Nameson</name>
    <version>10.1</version>
    <verdict>High</verdict>
</TestCase>
";

    public static void Main()
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(XML);

        var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/TestCase");

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestCase));

        var testcase = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(node.OuterXml)) as TestCase;

        Console.WriteLine(testcase.name);
        Console.WriteLine(testcase.version);
        Console.WriteLine(testcase.verdict);
    }
}
```

**[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JVCBfi)**

Comment: Worked well without much changes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize directly from your selected `XmlNode` by combining [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) with [`XmlNodeReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodereader.aspx) using the following extension method:

```
public static class XmlNodeExtensions
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XmlNode element, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        using (var reader = new ProperXmlNodeReader(element))
            return (T)(serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Deserialize(reader);
    }

    class ProperXmlNodeReader : XmlNodeReader
    {
        // Bug fix from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102275/deserialize-object-property-with-stringreader-vs-xmlnodereader
        public ProperXmlNodeReader(XmlNode node)
            : base(node)
        {
        }

        public override string LookupNamespace(string prefix)
        {
            return NameTable.Add(base.LookupNamespace(prefix));
        }
    }
}
```

This adds an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to `XmlNode` which invokes `XmlSerializer` to [deserialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y.aspx) the selected node to an instance of the generic type `T`.

Then do:

```
var testcase = node.Deserialize<TestCase>();
```

which is identical to:

```
var testcase = XmlNodeExtensions.Deserialize<TestCase>(node);
```

In your case the expected root element name of your `TestCase` class, namely `<TestCase>`, matches the actual node name.  If the node name does not match the expected root element name, you can tell `XmlSerializer` to expect a different root name by following the instructions in [XmlSerializer Performance Issue when Specifying XmlRootAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534810/xmlserializer-performance-issue-when-specifying-xmlrootattribute).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. My c# understanding is not that advanced so I am not sure what exactly the code you've provided me does. Would you mind giving me a brief explanation of the code? Thanks!

Comment: @JephGagnon - I added a brief explanation, but I'm not sure what you need to know.

Comment: It was more of a general understanding of what you did exactly. The link you provided gives me more information on that. I marked Negorath response as the answer because I can understand what was done, but I will definitely try this method also (and more importantly, understand it). Thank you.